# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n!}}{n}=-\log 2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I would like to know what's equal this: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n!}}{n}$  if it is also convergent as  :$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}=-\log 2$ ?.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Isn't $(-1)^{n!}=1$ for $n\ge2$? So this should behave like the harmonic series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n!$ is even for $n\geq 2$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n!}}{n}=-1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$, which diverges.

Comment: Man, you sure type faster than I can get here ;) +1

Comment: Well, your answer is longer...

Comment: Yeah, some sort of trade off  :D

Answer (score 2):

Notice that whenever $n\ge2$,

$$n!=1\times\color{red}2\times\dots\times n$$

Thus, $n!$ is even, and so $\color{blue}{(-1)^{n!}=1}$ for all $n\ge2$.

And so, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\color{blue}{(-1)^{n!}}}n=-1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\color{blue}1}n\to\infty$$

Comment: your last line should began from n=1 not n=0 as singularity point

Comment: @user51189 Thank you, that was my bad.